# Which parts of Doom (1993) are open source and which are not?

Tags: software-engineering, open-source

As the original publication of the source code states, you still need an original copy of the game:

https://www.doomworld.com/idgames/idstuff/source/doomsrc

What exactly do you need from those original copies?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you got downvoted for this

Comment: @Natalo77 I'd suspect the question was downvoted for not demonstrating research effort. The page linked in the question itself contains the answer.

Comment: @DMGregory very true - thanks for explaining a possibility

Comment: True. Maybe the question wasn't well phrased. I meant to say that I can't find a reason why you wouldn't be able to use any other Copyright free wad.

Comment: What leads you to believe you wouldn't be able to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doom is divided into two components:

- The game engine.
- The game data.

Of these, **[the source code which was released](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM) is for the game engine only**, and as the [readme](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/blob/master/README.TXT) notes, only for the Linux version, as id Software had used third-party sound code for the DOS version, which they were unable to open-source.

The game data is contained in [WAD files](https://doomwiki.org/wiki/WAD) and includes the following elements:

- Maps.
- Textures.
- Sprites.
- Sounds.
- 2D GUI images.
- Music.

**None of the game data is open-sourced** and you will still need a commercial copy of the game to access it.

**One other item which is open-sourced** is t[he DOS Doom "Setup" program](https://github.com/id-Software/idsetup), which was used to configure sound and other options outside of the game engine.

Other official Doom ports are a mixed-bag; the Windows port from the 90s is apparently lost, but source for the IOS port is available ([1](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-iOS) and [2](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-IOS2)) as is source for [the version that was bundled with the Doom 3 BFG Edition](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3-BFG/tree/master/doomclassic).

Answer (score 1):

You need the doom.wad file that came with it. Alternatively, you can find total conversion mods for free various places online and then you don’t need anything. Although in that case you are looking at an entirely different game, just running on the same engine.

Comment: Can other wad files be used in replacement of the ones mentioned?

Comment: @KoltPenny You can use a custom IWAD (initial WAD) as a replacement for the original Doom IWADs ([Freedoom](https://freedoom.github.io/) being the most notable one). However, PWADs (patch WADs) such as mods and most total conversions require an IWAD to work. Nearly all Doom mods work well when using Freedoom, but the art styles may sometimes visibly clash.

When you combine an open source Doom source port with Freedoom, you get a freely and commercially redistributable package (as long as you follow the source port's license and Freedoom's license).